# add users to beta testing iphone app

Tags: iphone

I use testflight to administer beta versions of my app, problem is that the provioning profile only allows me to test on one device, do I have to keep creating a new certificate in keychain to change it? Or is there an easier way to either

a) change the device

b) add another device to an existing build

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a new device to an existing build.  You have to:

1. Add another device in the Provisioning Portal.
2. Modify the existing ad hoc distribution profile to include the new device.
3. Remove your existing Ad Hoc provisioning profile from the Xcode organizer.
4. Install the new provisioning profile in Xcode.
5. Create a new build in Xcode that is signed with this profile.
6. Upload the new build to TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally flow is that each user(developer here) will have a keychain. Using that he will request a certificate. Now when you create a provisioning profile you have to select names of the developer whom you want to use that. So only those users will be able to debug application on device.

Now if you want to use one user's key chain and certificate for all the you have to export it from his key chain utility and import it in other. Same way you can export provisioning profile also. You can easily find methods for that on internet(I am avoiding this because it has nothing to do with programming).